# Show ranges as legend for highcharts angular gauge

Tags: highcharts

I would like to display the ranges as my legend. An example gauge would be something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/kbvC3/light/)

Can I have it so that I can have legends with colors and the text [Bad/Good/Excellent] based on the values?

```
plotBands: [{
            from: 0,
            to: 120,
            color: '#55BF3B' // green
        }, {
            from: 120,
            to: 160,
            color: '#DDDF0D' // yellow
        }, {
            from: 160,
            to: 200,
            color: '#DF5353' // red
        }]
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just create separate series for legend, and enable them: http://jsfiddle.net/kbvC3/734/

```
    series: [{
        name: 'Speed',
        data: [80],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' km/h'
        }
    }, {
        showInLegend: true,
        name: "Bad",
        color: '#55BF3B' // green   
    }, {
        showInLegend: true,
        name: "Good",
        color: '#DDDF0D' // yellow  
    }, {
        showInLegend: true,
        name: "Excellent",
        color: '#DF5353' // red  
    }]
```